# MyISAM problem after moving datadir of a MySQL database

Tags: permissions, filesystem, mysql

I recently moved my MySQL database data directory from the default location `/var/lib/mysql` onto a new harddrive located in `/media/..UID../mysql`, following the steps you can find in several posts.

1. stop the MySQL
2. Copy the old folder to the new location
3. Change the `datadir` in the `[mysqld]` of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
4. Change the two entries in the AppArmor configuration
5. Adjust the user rights from the data dir
6. Restart AppArmor
7. Restart MySql

After those steps I tried to create a new database and it worked, it appears also in the new folder. Then I created a new InnoDB table and it also worked and it places the `*frm` file into the `/mysql/new` folder. But then I wanted to create a MyISAM table into this database, I received the error

`#1 - Can't create/write to file '/media/..UID../mysql/new/tableName.MYI' (Errcode: 13)`

I tried already to set all permission to 777, as I thought it is a permission problem (but as InnoDB can write into that folder, I cannot see why MyISAM cannot!?). For me it looks like that the MyISAM engine needs somewhere else special permission in order to write it's files, but I do not know where.

First I thought that it is a mounting problem of that new harddrive, but then again - the InnoDB can create database folders and also create files inside these folders.

So, any help is appreciated, if someone had a similar issue after moving a MyISAM table and could give some hints where to look or what else to try.

Thanks a lot already in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

Here's what worked on Ubuntu 12.04

To move datafiles from `/var/lib/mysql` to `/newdir_path/newdir`

```
sudo mysql stop
sudo rsync -av /var/lib/mysql /newdir_path/newdir ## like copy, but keeps rights
sudo -H gedit /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

change `datadir` to `/newdir_path/newdir`

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

instead of:

```
/var/lib/mysql/ r,
/var/lib/mysql/** /rwk
```

enter:

```
/newdir_path/newdir/ r,
/newdir_path/newdir/** rwk,
```

Now run:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor restart 
sudo chown mysql:mysql <b>/newdir_path
sudo start mysql
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer after so long time, unfortunately I reinstalled the computer in the meanwhile and solved the problem that way. But once I have to move the DB again, I am happy to try out your steps. As I cannot try it right now, I am going to accept this solution as possibly working.